# R programming, categorizing the data

Tags: r

The data set wineData contains an attribute called quality with numerical values ranging from 1 to 8. I was trying to categorize it by below code:

```
wineData$taste <- NA
wineData$taste[which(wineData$quality< 6)] <- bad
wineData$taste[which(wineData$quality>6)] <- excellent
wineData$taste[which(wineData$quality=6)] <- normal
wineData$taste <- factor(wineData$taste)
wineData`
```

Here only the quality>6 is categorized as excellent and all others as NA. Why it is not able to categorize others ?

These are the errors I am getting.

> wineData$taste[which(wineData$quality>6)] <- excellent Error: object 'excellent' not found 
>   wineData$taste[which(wineData$quality==6)] <- normal Error: object 'normal' not found

Comment: `=` is assignemnt, use `==` for equality testing. You should have got an error message running that code.

Comment: These are the errors I am getting. wineData$taste[which(wineData$quality>6)] <- excellent
Error: object 'excellent' not found
> wineData$taste[which(wineData$quality==6)] <- normal
Error: object 'normal' not found

Comment: Yeah, telling us about the errors you get is usually a good idea. You need to quote strings.

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this

```
wineData$taste <- NA
    wineData$taste[which(wineData$quality< 6)] <- "bad"
    wineData$taste[which(wineData$quality>6)] <- "excellent"
    wineData$taste[which(wineData$quality==6)] <- "normal"
    wineData$taste <- factor(wineData$taste)
    wineData
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `dplyr::case_when()`

```r
library(dplyr)
wineData <- wineData %>%
  mutate(
    taste = case_when(
      quality < 6 ~ "bad",
      quality > 6 ~ "excellent",
      quality = 6 ~ "normal",
      TRUE        ~  NA
    ),
    taste = as.factor(taste, levels = c("bad", "normal", "excellent")
  )
```